# org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power Settings Ignored in Xubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: xubuntu, battery, hibernate, dconf, xfce4-power-manager

In `dconf-editor` I navigated to `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power` and set `percentage-action` to *40*, `percentage-critical` to *45*, `percentage-low` to *50*, `critical-battery-action` to *hibernate*, and `use-time-for-policy` to *false*.

These settings are being completely ignored. No notifications pop up about low battery, and my laptop simply performs a hard shutdown when the battery gets too low (I've made sure hibernation works with my laptop). Is there some sort of conflict with `xfce4-power-manager`?

Comment: Why would you expect Xfce to use GNOME settings?

Comment: @Bill I went on the xubuntu irc and this is what somebody told me to do. Would I have to replace `xfce4-power-manager` with `gnome-power-manager`?